# C# Winforms: Disable tracking of a binded EF object to avoid context updates till "Update" is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

So, I have a form with a list of categories binded to a `DataGridView`, and when I double-click on one of the rows, a new form with details of the category is open, and also allow the user to edit or remove the selected category.

Here is the code of both forms:

**FrmCategoryList.cs**

```
public partial class FrmCategoryList : Form
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public FrmCategoryList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dbContext = new DbContext();
    }

    private void FrmCategoryList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillGrid();
    }

    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillGrid();
    }

    private void dgvCategories_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            var category = (Category)grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
            var frmCategoryView = new FrmCategoryView(category.Id, dbContext);

            if (frmCategoryView.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                FillGrid();
        }
    }

    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frmCategoryView = new FrmCategoryView(0, dbContext);

        if (frmCategoryView.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            FillGrid();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void FillGrid()
    {
        categoryBinding.DataSource = dbContext.Categories.Where(p => p.Description.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text)).ToList();
    }

    private void FrmCategoryList_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        dbContext?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**FrmCategoryView.cs**

```
public partial class FrmCategoryView : Form
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;
    private Category category;

    public FrmCategoryView(int categoryId, DbContext dbContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dbContext = dbContext;

        if (categoryId == 0)
        {
            category = new Category();
            btnSave.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            category = dbContexto.Categories.Include(c => c.Products).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == categoryId);
            btnUpdate.Visible = true;
            btnDelete.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void FrmCategoryView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", category, "Description");
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (category.Validate(dbContext))
        {
            dbContext.Categories.Add(category);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Category added!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            Close();
        }
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (category.Validate(dbContext))
        {
            dbContext.Categories.Attach(category);
            dbContext.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Category updated!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            Close();
        }
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("¿Are you sure to delete this category?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (category.Products.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot delete a category with dependencies.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            dbContext.Categories.Remove(category);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Category deleted!.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            Close();
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        Close();
    }
}
```

So, the problem comes when I edit some field of a category, and then close the form without pressing the Update button. The context isn't disposed until the `FrmCategoryList` is closed, and the category object from `FrmCategoryView` is binded to the text, so the context is updated but changes are not saved to the database. So, if I open other category and actually update it, the previous change will be saved too when calling `SaveChanges()` because the context keep track of the changes that the user "discard".

How can I do to solve this? I could re-initialize the context in `FrmCategoryView`, but then the changes will not be in `FrmCategoryList` context in case I actually save something, and I don't know how to force EF to check database even for already tracked objects.

Also, maybe there is some way to detach the object from the context, and then re-attach it when Update button is pressed. I tried with AsNoTracking() but an error happens when trying to re-attach on Update: it's duplicated because an instance of that object was created in the list form.

Sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand!

**EDIT:**

Now I tried to set the Entity State of category to Detached right after getting it using the Id in `FrmCategoryView` constructor, with:

```
dbContext.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

It doesn't work the first time I close the view form: the grid row get updated because the context is updated, even when the `category` entry is set as Detached. But the next onces, it doesn't happend. It works like it should work. The changes I make to `category` aren't tracked by the context until I re-attach it and save changes on Update button.

Comment: Don't use the same instance of context for edit form.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you have used `ShowDialog`. Read the second point in remarks section of below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=netframework-4.7.2

In this scenario the form is not disposed.

> you have displayed the form using ShowDialog. In these cases, you will
>   need to call Dispose manually to mark all of the form's controls for
>   garbage collection.

Or as you want Modal dialog, clean up the context by handling `closing` event, if you do not have problem with other controls living till you close parent form.

Comment: Well, i didn't know that closing a form opened by ShowDialog() doesn't dispose it, but it's not whats causing the problem. Disposing the form do not discard the changes tracked by the context.

Comment: Yes. It will not, You have to take care of the sanity work, may be form closing event could be a better place.

Comment: But how? Check the edit I made to the original post.

Comment: Could you please try the same in form closing event??

Comment: Same result. I answered with a solution I found. Give it a look and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

To recap, this are the changes I made to the original code:

- Added `AsNoTracking()` when filling the grid in `FrmCategoryList`.
- Detach `category` from the context after getting it using the id in `FrmCategoryView` constructor.
- Re-attach `category` before saving changes on Update and Delete, with Modified and Deleted states respectively.

After some tests, I didn't find any issue. Any suggestions are appreciated.